# Search and replace parts of string with a value in php with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace fields given below with actual values from an array (with values 864 and 987) of datafields, but I don't know how to replace `[crowdpdf-total=field_585b0b3288d2e]` with for example `864` and `[crowdpdf-total=field_585b0b3288d2f]` with `987`.

**The array:**

```
array (
'field_585b0b3288d2e'=> 864,
'field_585b0b3288d2f => 987
)
```

**The string:**

```
etc etc etc content
[crowdpdf-total=field_585b0b3288d2e] 
etc etc [crowdpdf-total=field_585b0b3288d2f] 
etc content
```

I'm good at many things, but for some reasons, I've never quite understood regex entirely... I guess regex is the way of replacing `[crowdpdf-total={nameoffield}]` with an actual value? Is regex the way to go here?

**I want the string to be:**

```
etc etc etc content
864 
etc etc 987
etc content
```

**Clarification:**
The actual value I understand how to replace, so I could do like replacement that
`[crowdpdf-total=864]` and I could remove `[crowdpdf-total=` by just replacing `[crowdpdf-total=` with empty string, but then I would have an extra bracket at the end of each value.

Comment: Time to understand it entirely read this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do). (Don't give me the fish but teach me to fish!)

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス - comments like that does not really add any value, but thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for this. A simple string replacement will do:

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOT
etc etc etc content
[crowdpdf-total=field_585b0b3288d2e] 
etc etc [crowdpdf-total=field_585b0b3288d2f] 
etc content
EOT;

$replacements = [
    'field_585b0b3288d2e' => 864,
    'field_585b0b3288d2f' => 987,
];

foreach ($replacements as $find => $replace) {
    $string = str_replace("[crowdpdf-total=$find]", $replace, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

It outputs:

```
etc etc etc content
864 
etc etc 987 
etc content
```

[Test it online](https://3v4l.org/i4L1u), if you wish.

Comment: ahh. of course! I thought I was going about the wrong direction. Thanks for guiding me into right direction! :-)